# Why do the two layers of a phospholipid bilayer stick together?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organophosphorus-compounds, lipids

Every answer I can find about why phospholipids form a bilayer says the same thing: hydrophilic heads associate with water, hydrophobic tails do not, so they arrange themselves with heads facing outward. Makes sense.

What I have not been able to find an explanation for is why the two layers of a bilayer sheet stick together in a cell. Why aren't the phospholipids of the upper layer pulled away by passing water molecules, like how salt ions are pulled away from a salt crystal? Why doesn't the same thing happen in the bottom layer? And what keeps the two layers bonded when the fatty acid tails have (in my understanding) little to no attraction to each other?
[image]

Comment: You may want to read about the hydrophobic effect. Also, forces at the molecular level, and the behavior of matter generally, is very different from what we are familiar with in our macroscopic world. The microscopic world of condensed matter is viscous and motion is dominated by diffusion. Of course, once biological systems get involved things can get more complicated.

Comment: Also, that picture is a cartoon representation. Things are far more disorderly.